# Random forest classification on QGIS gets stocked at 66% with an error message whose conditions have been met

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins, classification, land-classification, random-forest

I am running a random forest classification on QGIS using dzesaka pluggin, after picking my training sites and running the classification,
it gets to 66% and a prompt message appears that i ensure that my class ID are only integers & same projection as raster which is fine but doesn't continue after the message and its stocked.

I have tried different versions of QGIS and they are all coming out tge same.

---

It doesn't proceed at 66% but shows that it's still running.
Even after about half an hour nothing still happens.

Comment: What does "stocked" mean?

Comment: Can you provide a little bit more detail about your inputs? Pasting the exact error message can also be helpful when trying to debug an issue.

Answer (score 0):

See what I saw today as I was trying the classification with semi automatic classification plugin[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).